Мне нужно чтобы в документе высчитывалась общая стоимость с каждой строки
Мне нужно чтобы в документе высчитывалась общая стоимость с каждой строки
&НаКлиенте
Процедура РасходКоличествоИзрасходованногоТопливаПриИзменении(Элемент)
    
    ТЧ = Объект.Расход;
    Сумма = 0;
    Для Каждого Стр Из ТЧ Цикл
        Сумма = Сумма + Стр.КоличествоИзрасходованногоТоплива * Стр.СтоимостьТоплива;
    КонецЦикла;
    Объект.ОбщаяСуммаРасхода = Сумма;

КонецПроцедуры



Добавить событие РасходПриИзменении
&НаКлиенте
Процедура РасходПриИзменении(Элемент)
    ТЧ=Объект.Расход;
    Сумма=0;
    Для Каждого Стр Из ТЧ Цикл      
        СтоимостьКаждойСтроки = Стр.КоличествоИзрасходованногоТоплива*Стр.СтоимостьТоплива;
        Стр.ОбщаяСтоимостьСКаждойСтроки = СтоимостьКаждойСтроки;
        Сумма=Сумма +  СтоимостьКаждойСтроки ;
    КонецЦикла;
    Объект.ОбщаяСуммаРасхода = Сумма;

КонецПроцедуры

